# ActiveMQ Mirrored Queues on separate brokers

Tags: replication, activemq-classic, mirroring, messagebroker

Is it possible to set up [mirrored queues](http://activemq.apache.org/mirrored-queues.html) on different broker instances, residing on different machines? If so, how?

If not, what component(s) might I need to subclass/override to do something homegrown?

Comment: I think this question shows research (find any other article on the internet that addresses configuring ActiveMQ mirrored brokers on different machines!), is constructive and is helpful. It is definitely a "real question" and a definitive answer for it would help out a lot of current and future ActiveMQ users. Please let me know what the reason for the closevote was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure whay your incentive is for this setup.

If you have multiple brokers in a network, you can't really tell which machine a certain message is on (since it's forwarded to the broker where there is a connected consumer).

If all you need is wiretapping to a totally different ActiveMQ server, you can use [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) for that (it's included in ActiveMQ).

You just need to configure a connector to each ActiveMQ instance. 
Actually, in a [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882523/replay-messages-sent-over-activemq/13891459#13891459) to another question, I wrote a small Camel route that copies messages from every queue starting with `FOO.` to another queue with the name `COPY.<queue name>`. It might be useful in this case too.