# Best way to mimic production traffic from one ActiveMQ cluster to a QA one

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm trying to debug issues with a production ActiveMQ setup but cannot try scenarios on production, nor can I produce all scenarios in Production in QA. What I would like to do is tap the production ActiveMQ and copy all messages from Production to a QA bus setup in similar fashion. Does anyone know if such a Filter/Plugin already exist for doing something of this nature? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Is this **[useful to you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882523/replay-messages-sent-over-activemq)**?